# How to move items on the screen for a game using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dreamweaver

I want the img files to move across the screen and will disappear on click, after all are gone there will be a popup to show completion. However, only half my code works and the img files are stuck stationary.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

   function runIt(me) {
      $(me).css("top",Math.random()*800)
      .animate({"left":"1200px"},Math.random()*3000+1500,function(){$(me).css("top",Math.random()*800)})
      .animate({"left":"-150px"},Math.random()*3000+1500,function(){$(me).css("top",Math.random()*800);runIt(me)});
   }
   $(".target").each(function(){runIt($(this))});

score = 0;
function calcScore(me){
  $(me).hide();
  score++;
  $("#message").html("You shot "+score);
  if(score==8){
    alert("You got all of them!");
  }
}
</script>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="background">
<div class="target" onclick="calcScore(this)"><img src="images/bottle.png" width="80" height="80" alt=""/></div>
<div class="target" onclick="calcScore(this)"><img src="images/bottle.png" width="80" height="80" alt=""/></div>
<div class="target" onclick="calcScore(this)"><img src="images/bottle.png" width="80" height="80" alt=""/></div>
<div class="target" onclick="calcScore(this)"><img src="images/bottle.png" width="80" height="80" alt=""/></div>
<div class="target" onclick="calcScore(this)"><img src="images/bottle.png" width="80" height="80" alt=""/></div>
<div class="target" onclick="calcScore(this)"><img src="images/bottle.png" width="80" height="80" alt=""/></div>
<div class="target" onclick="calcScore(this)"><img src="images/bottle.png" width="80" height="80" alt=""/></div>
<div class="target" onclick="calcScore(this)"><img src="images/bottle.png" width="80" height="80" alt=""/></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix it, Just add this css in your page

```
.target {
    position: absolute;
}
```

and put your trigger code `$(".target").each(function(){runIt($(this))});` in document ready as below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".target").each(function(){runIt($(this))});
})
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks! The code work, but now that the image movement is random, sometimes they exit my background image of 1280x720px, is there a way to limit them?

Comment: For that, you have to give 0 instead of a negative value in left as following Replace `animate({"left":"-150px"}` with `animate({"left":"0px"}`

Comment: I've tried that but the problem persists. I dont have problems of it exiting the width, but instead it goes below my background image, exiting the height of it.

Comment: Then you have to tune the offset you use for changing the top. As of now the offset is 800. change that to 600 in all three places. That fixes the issue

Comment: Hi once again, I have centered my background image using text-align:center and also padding, however, now the things start from the left outside of the image, is there a way I can fix this?